# User login over Api in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am working on an API in symfony where users authenticate using a json web token. There is a bundle to provide this here: https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle.

There is documentation on the project page on how to set everything up. This bundle relies on the standard "form_login" configuration that is backed by the class defined in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/Security/Factory/FormLoginFactory.php.

The bundle provides success and failure listeners for authentication that short circuits the request and returns a JsonResponse with the token or an error with the appropriate response code.

Using the sample configuration on the project page, everything is working as described. The problem is that these predefined config factories such as "form_login" set cookies and many other behaviours that is not required in a stateless api.

The security component defines a config option "stateless" that is defined in the symfony book on security.

However the documentation above clearly states "If you use a form login, Symfony2 will create a cookie even if you set stateless to true."

The "form_login" has many options for redirecting or forwarding to the login page if the user is unauthenticated that isn't required for an api.

Also a lot of other functionality you may want to use, such as the SwitchUserListener is very much ingrained in the traditional development model where the server just returns html.

I'm looking to create a lightweight way to plug into symfony security using this bundle and disabling the other unneeded checks.

With JWT, no login is actually required, we need an unauthenticated route that we send a username and password to (over SSL) using the authorization header that returns the token. For the other protected routes we simply provide this token. This part is already provided by the bundle, I just need a stripped down way to get the initial token without invoking unneeded symfony code.

I found this example http://miguel.ibero.me/en/post/2012-04-04/symfony-rest-api.html which implements the code to get a token in a simple controller, bypassing the firewall.

I am looking for a better way to implement this using the firewall. I suspect I will have to create my own security factory such as "form_login".

I could use the http basic auth method to get the token, but I do not want symfony to present the username/password window. I would like the authenticator to check for the authorized header and simply return a message and response code whether it is successful or not.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

I created my own bundle to deal with this: https://github.com/gfreeau/GfreeauGetJWTBundle